# Style the alternate row differently in table layout while searching

Tags: java, codenameone

I am using table layout.I alternate the bg color of table rows (grey & white strip) but when i use search (code below), i have to restyle the table. In the code below, i am able to style only the single column. How can i style all five column. I tried few things but all in vain? Any help is appreciated. Thankyou.

```
    searchTextField.addDataChangeListener(new DataChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void dataChanged(int type, int index) {
            String getTextField = searchTextField.getText().toLowerCase();
            int counter = 0;
            int counterVisible = 0;
            boolean show = false;
            TextArea ta = new TextArea();
            for (Component c : containerTableData) {
                c.setName("searchContainer");
                Container cnt;
                cnt = (Container) c;

                if (counter % 5 == 0) {
                    ta = (TextArea) cnt.getComponentAt(0);
                    ta.setName("" + counter);
                    show = ta.getText().toLowerCase().indexOf(getTextField) > -1;
                }
                cnt.setHidden(!show);
                cnt.setVisible(show);

                if (cnt.isVisible()) {
                    cnt.setUIID("isVisible");
                    if (counterVisible % 2 == 0) {
                        ta.getParent().getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
                        ta.getParent().getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xcccccc);
                    } else {
                        ta.getParent().getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
                        ta.getParent().getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xffffff);
                    }
                    counterVisible++;
                }
                counter++;
            }
            containerTableData.animateLayout(200);
        }
    });
```

What i get now is this. I need entire row of same bg color

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting the background you are calling `ta.getParent().getAllStyles()` instead of `cnt.getAllStyles()`.